# Image objects dispersion and diversity measures

Tags: image-processing, measurement, connected-components

I have images like below:

[image: Img]

I want to find some measures describing black spots dispersion and diversity.

First measures I use are mass center off all black spots, mean area of spot, stdev of area need more ideas.

I want measures to describe irregularity, differences etc.

Comment: off the top of my head you could look at spot eccentricity, perimeter length, average perimeter curvature. You could also look at spatial correlation between all these parameters. What is relevant really depends on what you want to know.

Comment: the squared average perimeter divided by surface will give the "roundness" if each spot independently of its size (and pi for a disk)

Comment: Could you review my answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may treat those blobs as [connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_(graph_theory)).
Then you may use many of the properties in MATLAB's [`regionprops()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html) function:

1. Circularity.
2. Eccentricity.
3. Euler Number.
4. Max Feret Properties.

I would also add the Fractal Dimension.